# Includes does not eager load a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, eager-loading

I have two models

```
class Course
    belongs_to :content_picture
end

class ContentPicture
end
```

When I try to load the Courses and eager load all the pictures I get N+1 queries and I would like to make it in two queries

I've tried includes, joins, eager_load

Results:

```
Course.all
```

gives

```
 Course Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses"
  ContentPicture Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "content_pictures".* FROM "content_pictures" WHERE "content_pictures"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
  ContentPicture Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "content_pictures".* FROM "content_pictures" WHERE "content_pictures"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
```

With includes:

```
Course.includes(:content_picture).all
```

results in:

```
Course.includes(:content_picture).all
  Course Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses"
  ContentPicture Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "content_pictures".* FROM "content_pictures" WHERE "content_pictures"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
  ContentPicture Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "content_pictures".* FROM "content_pictures" WHERE "content_pictures"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
```

With eager load and with joins it is the same.

Comment: Try without `.all` `Course.includes(:content_picture)`

Comment: 1. What is your rails version?  2. Do you have any code in the `Course` model that could use the relation `content_picture` like `ContentPicture.find(self.content_picture_id)`? 3. If you remove all but the `belongs_to :content_picture` from the `Course` model, does the problem still happen?

Comment: What's the rest of the code you are running? `Course.includes(:content_picture).all` does not iterate over the `content_pictures`, is there more code you're not showing?

Comment: Pavan - Course.includes(:content_picture) results in 2 queries.

Comment: @MrYoshiji - rails version is 4.2.8. Turns out that there is an "after_initialize" block and this is causing the problem. Thanks for the hint to remote everythin

Comment: @m.simonborg yes, there is more code, but it is too much and I though it was unrelated to the questions. Turns out it is - there is an after_initialize block

Comment: what's the after_initialize code? did you figure out the solution?

Comment: after_initialize do 
   self.content_picture ||= ContentPicture.new
  end

Answer (score 1):

Because of a hint from @MrYoshiji I was able to find that this was caused because of an after_initialize block

```
after_initialize do 
    self.content_picture ||= ContentPicture.new
end
```

After removing the block the query worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You would try this out

`Course.includes(:content_picture).where("content_picture.id = ?", content_picture_id)`

Comment: I don't know the id of the content_picture when the request is constructed because it is for many things

Comment: Then you should try it with `has_many` relationship to the class ContentPicture.
After that you would be able to access `Course.includes(:content_pictures)`
or else you need to do operation to finding out the content_picture_id.

Comment: I was able without changing to has_many. Just had to remove the after_initialize block